# Java morphia $sample howto?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm trying to retrieve a single document from a random collection without loading the entire collection into a list.

I know I want to use aggregation but I'm not sure how to actually perform it with Java/Morphia and I can't find anything in the readme on it either.

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
)
```

How can I execute this query using Morphia (ideally) or via the raw Mongodb driver?

All questions around getting a random document seem to be before 3.2 and look more complicated than I think it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, while the aggregate is now deprecated it will do for my use case

```
public void findRandomObject() {
    BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject("$sample", new BasicDBObject("size", 1));
    AggregationOutput output = getCollection().aggregate(object);

    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        LOGGER.info("output >> " + result);
    }
}
```